# Fill an Item Grid with background pictures from Sqlite DB in a Windows Store app

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

My datasource for this app is a SQLite DB. It all works pretty fine except of one point.

I want to fill an item grid with data from that DB and use the pictures stored in that db as background images.

```
public class Movie_Picture
{
        [SQLite.AutoIncrement, SQLite.PrimaryKey]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
        public int Movie_id { get; set; }
}
```

If I query this table with

```
 var query = connection.QueryAsync<Movie_Picture>("Select * from Movie_Picture");
```

i can fill the item grid and each item in that grid gets his label from Movie_id and id but the images aren´t displayed

The XAML for this grid looks like

```
   <GridView x:Name="DataGrid1" SelectionChanged="DataGrid1_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding}">      
     <GridView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
        <Grid  Width="300" Height="300" removed="{x:Null}">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}" Margin="0,140,0,0"></TextBlock>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Movie_id}" Margin="0,180,0,0"></TextBlock>
         <Image x:Name="itemImage" Source="{Binding Picture, Converter={StaticResource    BytesToImageConverter}}" />
        </Grid>
       </DataTemplate>
      </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

edit :

code for converter

```
    public class BytesToImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type typeName, object parameter, string language)
        {
            if (value != null && value is byte[])
            {
                byte[] bytes = value as byte[];
                Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();

                image.SetSource(new MemoryRandomAccessStream(stream));

                return image;
            }

            return null;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type typeName, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Show us code for `BytesToImageConverter`.

Comment: Added code for the converter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG :)

Found the problem. It was the converter.

```
public class BytesToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type typeName, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value != null && value is byte[])
        {
            byte[] bytes = value as byte[];
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();

            image.SetSourceAsync(new MemoryRandomAccessStream(stream));

            return image;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type typeName, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

The solution was to change `image.SetSource()` to `image.SetSourceAsync`